# feature.xml requires vs includes

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In the `feature.xml` file you can specify dependencies on other features/plugins by using the `requires` element or the `includes` element.

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is that included features will be packaged with your feature when it is built. Required features are not packaged with the feature, but are expected to be present when you install the feature.

From the Eclipse [help](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Feditors%2Ffeature_editor%2Fdependencies.htm&cp=4_3_2_1_4):

- `includes` specifies features that become part of the defining feature as subfeatures
- `requires` specify features that need to be present *before* installing the defining feature

Answer (score 9):

`requires` means your feature depends on another independent feature (such as one of the standard Eclipse features).

`includes` adds another feature as a child of your feature - so you can have one main feature with several children. If you look at the Eclipse About > Installation Details > Installed Software tab you will see several features with children.